# Implementation of Flatlist/SectionList of Custom Card view's

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to implement a list of custom card view's(Like the CollectionView in ios with custom collectionview cell). How can I achieve this any idea's or tutorials plz. I do not want to use third party. Could someone help me out.

Comment: rtfm? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist

Comment: simply take a look at these two class implemented for ios and android seperatly
https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/react-native-cardview/tree/master/libs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a Collection View like a solution with React Native FlatList. To make a grid view you have to use [numColumns](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#numcolumns) prop. The following code segment will support you.

```
class MyListItem extends React.PureComponent {

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.item}>
          <Text>
            {this.props.title}
          </Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
export default class App extends React.Component {
  data = [
    {
      "id":1,
      "label":"Label 01"
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "label":"Label 02"
    },
    {
      "id":3,
      "label":"Label 03"
    },
    {
      "id":4,
      "label":"Label 04"
    },
    {
      "id":5,
      "label":"Label 05"
    },
    {
      "id":6,
      "label":"Label 06"
    },
    {
      "id":7,
      "label":"Label 07"
    },
    {
      "id":8,
      "label":"Label 08"
    },
    {
      "id":9,
      "label":"Label 09"
    }
  ]
   _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;

    renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <MyListItem
      id={item.id}
      title={item.label}
    />
  );

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
        data={this.data}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        numColumns={3}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#add8e6',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',    
    flex:1,
    margin: 5,
    height: 100
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Dinith, this is close to my question, what is this "Constants.statusBarHeight" value, & where should I declare it

Comment: Actually. I have tried this one on snack.expo and that Constants imported from expo. You can user StatusBar.currentHeight by importing Statusbar from react-native or use any value you like as the topPadding value.

Comment: In Flatlist items can we customize the width of a item ?

Comment: Yes @iOSDev, You can customize the item properties with custom styles.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are trying to do. In minimum, a FlatList expects the following props;

- **data**: An array of data. (Each data point is one row in your list)
- **renderItem**: How to transform a data point into a row. (Think of your render function, but for just a row.)
- **keyExtractor**: How to create keys(think of them as ids) for these rows to keep track of them.

In the end you would need to do the following (keep in mind data structure, keyExtractor and what is being rendered is completely arbitrary);

```
  <FlatList
    data={[{ id: 1, text: 'Hello' }, { id: 2, text: 'StackOverflow!' }]}
    keyExtractor={item => `texts#${item.id}`}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (<Text>{item.text}</Text>)}
  />
```

More extensive data about this can be found at [official React Native documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist).